# Windows 8 remote desktop

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop

I got a workstation here in a private network running Windows 8 Pro. This computer is used to test new features or [Metro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_%28design_language%29) applications. The users connect via remote desktop and that works pretty fine so far.

My problem is now, that if a user is already connected to the workstation, he will be kicked off if another user connects. In older versions there was an option that the current user gets a message to accept or decline.

After hours of searching I couldn't find a solution for Windows 8. How do I solve this problem, or isn't it possible anymore?

Comment: Have you tried to use gpedit.msc? -> Administrative Templates \ Windows components \ Remote desktop services \ Remote desktop session host \  Connections -> 
"Set rules of remote control of remote desktop services" (also Windows 7 does not do the asking by default)

Comment: Hey Offler, thanks for your post! 
I tried to change the settings at the gpedit.msc and it looked like the function i was looking for. Then i noticed that its only supported for:

Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2003, Windows 7, Windows Vista und Windows XP

:-/

Comment: I tested it on Windows 8, and it worked despite what the notes say.  I think a) Microsoft may not have updated the notes, b) 'Offler' is a genius!

Comment: Ok i made it work with Offner's tip (Big Thanks so far!) 
Now the problem occurs when i try to connect with the same account. But i guess there's no way to solve this or at least it makes no sense  =). Thanks for help =)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 does not offer multiple [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) sessions out of the box. In older OS'es you could buy more Terminal Services (TS) Client Access Licenses (CALs) and [Windows Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003) had two by default.

There is however a way to set up multiple RDP connections which I found in an answer to Super User question *[How do I enable terminal services on Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/503156)*.